# Product Attribute sorting not applied when attribute relies on another

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, product-view

I'm currently building a site in Magento 2 and am trying to get sorting working for product attributes on the product listing page. I have a Size attribute which doesn't respect the sorting specified in the admin.

When it's the only attribute on the product the sorting is applied fine:

[image: Sorting shown correctly]

When the attribute is dependant on a parent attribute (you have to select another attribute before the size attribute is loaded) they are sorted in alphabetical order rather than the one specified in the admin.

[image: Sorted by alphabetical order rather than what's in the admin]

I'm confident that it's not custom code causing this issue as the block is loaded from the Magento_Catalog module.